# Delphi - Convert (read) C++ NULL terminated array from dll call

Tags: c++, delphi

Help, I'm getting crazy :)

I'm playing around with TeamSpeak3 and have a dll call which returns an array of Clients (ID's) online. My problem is that it is returned in a structure I cannot figure out to read in Object Pascal.

The SDK manual specifies this:

---

```
This is what the docs says
To get a list of all currently visible clients on the specified virtual server:
unsigned intts3client_getClientList(serverConnectionHandlerID, result);
uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID;
anyID** result;
Parameters
• serverConnectionHandlerID
ID of the server connection handler for which the list of clients is requested.
• result
Address of a variable that receives a NULL-termianted array of client IDs. Unless an error occurs, the array must be released
using ts3client_freeMemory.
Returns ERROR_ok on success, otherwise an error code as defined in public_errors.h. If an error has occured, the
result array is uninitialized and must not be released.
```

---

This is my Delphi code so far.

```
type
  PPanyID = ^PAnyID;
  PanyID = ^anyID;
  anyID  = word;

// declaration looks like this, some guy called CodeJunkie ported it from C++)
function ts3client_getClientList(serverConnectionHandlerID: uint64; result: PPanyID): longword; cdecl; external CLIENT_DLL {$IFDEF MACOS}name '_ts3client_getClientList'{$ENDIF};
procedure TfrmMain.RequestOnlineClients;
var
  clientids : PAnyId;
  i : Integer;
begin

  error := ts3client_getClientList(FTSServerHandlerID, @clientids);
  if (error <> ERROR_ok) then
  begin
    if (ts3client_getErrorMessage(error, @errormsg) = ERROR_ok) then
    begin
      LogMsg(Format('Error requesting online clients: %s', [errormsg]));
      ts3client_freeMemory(errormsg);
    end;
  end else
      begin
         // Put in into some regular Object array here, but how the h...... 
         // Or at least interate the received array of ID's


      end;

end;
```

The example code in C++ looks like this and it works, I didn't write it :)

```
void showClients(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID) {
    anyID *ids;
    anyID ownClientID;
    int i;
    unsigned int error;

    printf("\nList of all visible clients on virtual server %llu:\n", (unsigned long long)serverConnectionHandlerID);
    if((error = ts3client_getClientList(serverConnectionHandlerID, &ids)) != ERROR_ok) {  /* Get array of client IDs */
        printf("Error getting client list: %d\n", error);
        return;
    }
    if(!ids[0]) {
        printf("No clients\n\n");
        ts3client_freeMemory(ids);
        return;
    }

    /* Get own clientID as we need to call CLIENT_FLAG_TALKING with getClientSelfVariable for own client */
    if((error = ts3client_getClientID(serverConnectionHandlerID, &ownClientID)) != ERROR_ok) {
        printf("Error querying own client ID: %d\n", error);
        return;
    }

    for(i=0; ids[i]; i++) {
        char* name;
        int talkStatus;

        if((error = ts3client_getClientVariableAsString(serverConnectionHandlerID, ids[i], CLIENT_NICKNAME, &name)) != ERROR_ok) {  /* Query client nickname... */
            printf("Error querying client nickname: %d\n", error);
            break;
        }

        if(ids[i] == ownClientID) {  /* CLIENT_FLAG_TALKING must be queried with getClientSelfVariable for own client */
            if((error = ts3client_getClientSelfVariableAsInt(serverConnectionHandlerID, CLIENT_FLAG_TALKING, &talkStatus)) != ERROR_ok) {
                printf("Error querying own client talk status: %d\n", error);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if((error = ts3client_getClientVariableAsInt(serverConnectionHandlerID, ids[i], CLIENT_FLAG_TALKING, &talkStatus)) != ERROR_ok) {
                printf("Error querying client talk status: %d\n", error);
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("%u - %s (%stalking)\n", ids[i], name, (talkStatus == STATUS_TALKING ? "" : "not "));
        ts3client_freeMemory(name);
    }
    printf("\n");

    ts3client_freeMemory(ids);  /* Release array */
}
```

Please, can anybody help out here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer you get back points to the first result. Doing `Inc(clientids)` moves you on to the next result. Keep going until you reach an `anyid` that is zero ("NULL").

(You also need to save the original value of `clientids` so you can pass it to the free function as the documentation says to avoid leaking the memory.)

Answer (score 0):

*G* is this for real, is this seriously the only way of reading arrays returned from a c++ dll? And will  this work with 64bit too?

```
procedure TfrmMain.RequestOnlineClients;
var
  ids : array of anyID;
  pids : PanyID;
  aid : anyID;
begin


  error := ts3client_getClientList(FTSServerHandlerID, @ids);
  if (error <> ERROR_ok) then
  begin
    if (ts3client_getErrorMessage(error, @errormsg) = ERROR_ok) then
    begin
      LogMsg(Format('Error requesting online clients: %s', [errormsg]));
      ts3client_freeMemory(errormsg);
    end;
  end else
      begin
         pids := @ids[0];
         while (pids^ <> 0) do
         begin
           aid := pids^;
           LogMsg(format('id %u',[aid]));
           inc(pids);
         end;
         ts3client_freeMemory(@pids^);
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Your error handling is off. Don't call `ts3client_freeMemory` when the function call fails. The documentation states that clearly. This API is very well defined indeed. I don't think you should be complaining about it.

Comment: Also, instead of `pids := @ids[0];` write `pids := ids;`

Comment: Thank you for replying David.  

1. What makes you say I'm freeing if the call fails, please explain?
2. What makes you think I'm complaining? 

I'm just frustrated because I'm not good enough to port the C++ code into Delphi - so if there's a complaint here then it's about my skills.

Comment: 3. pids := @ids[0]; cannot be translated to pids := ids;

Comment: 3. Oh I see that now. I assumed that ids was PAnyID because that would match the function declaration. So you've got a much bigger problem and that is that you are passing the address of a dynamic array to the function. That doesn't match the function declaration. Indeed there's no place for a dynamic array here. So you've still got a way to go to get this sorted out.

Comment: 1. Because you are. No need to discuss it. Your code is clear.

Comment: I think I could have helped you do this right but I saw the question too late and you'd already accepted and answer and posted your own answer. To be clear, the answer you accepted is just fine. You just need significant help with the code that's in your answer.

Comment: 2. Because the way the answer is written suggests that. OK, you are frustrated at yourself, but that's not totally clear in the answer. It's easy to misinterpret feelings and emotions when they are expressed in writing.

Comment: David, I'm new here - I'm not trying to offend anybody or criticize the teamspeak API. I trying to use it and it has frustrated me quite a bit that I do not understand how the "lists" of data are to be read.

I have now learned some more, thanks to you guys, and maybe I was too quick to accept, basically because it appeared to be working.

You claim there still are errors, and you may be right, would you please clarify this? Should I start another question for that purpose?

Comment: There certainly are errors in the code you have here. As I see it, it won't even compile because @ids is a type mismatch.

Comment: I have asked for help in a new thread, I would appreciate any help on the flaws in my code, please.
[New question link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105743/delphi-and-using-teamspeak-sdk)

Comment: I was wrong about the multiple calls to `ts3client_freeMemory`. You pass different things to each one. `ts3client_freeMemory(ids);` is presumably what you want, once you fix the dynamic array problem.