# Delphi and using Teamspeak SDK

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to use TeamSpeak3 SDK with my delphi my have come accross a few problems, the code compiles and appears to work, most of the code is example code from example projects, that's except the attempt to read the returned data.
 1. Do I free the memory correct?
 2. Do I read the returned data from the SDK correct or can it be done in a better way?

I have asked a question about this SDK in another thread, but I was obviously too quick to mark the thread as answered. :/

SDK Documentation:

To get a list of all currently visible clients on the specified virtual server:
**unsigned int ts3client_getClientList(serverConnectionHandlerID, result);**
uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID;
anyID** result;
Parameters
• serverConnectionHandlerID
ID of the server connection handler for which the list of clients is requested.
• result
Address of a variable that receives a NULL-termianted array of client IDs.
Unless an error occurs, the array must be released using ts3client_freeMemory.
Returns ERROR_ok on success, otherwise an error code as defined in public_errors.h. If an error has occured, the result array is uninitialized and must not be released.

A list of all channels on the specified virtual server can be queried with:
**unsigned int ts3client_getChannelList(serverConnectionHandlerID, result);**
uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID;
uint64** result;
Parameters
• serverConnectionHandlerID
ID of the server connection handler for which the list of channels is requested.
• result
Address of a variable that receives a NULL-termianted array of channel IDs. Unless an error occurs, the array must be released using ts3client_freeMemory.
Returns ERROR_ok on success, otherwise an error code as defined in public_errors.h. If an error has occured, the result array is uninitialized and must not be released.

> **unsigned int ts3client_getCaptureDeviceList (modeID, result);**     const char* modeID;   char**** result;

Parameters
• modeID
Defines the playback/capture mode to use. For different modes there might be different device lists. Valid modes are returned   ts3client_getDefaultPlayBackMode/ts3client_getDefaultCaptureMode and  ts3client_getPlaybackModeList/ts3client_getCaptureModeList.
• result
Address of a variable that receives a NULL-terminated array { { char* deviceName, char* deviceID }, { char* deviceName, char* deviceID }, ... , NULL }.
Unless the function returns an error, the elements of the array and the array itself need to be freed using ts3client_freeMemory.

Returns ERROR_ok on success, otherwise an error code as defined in public_errors.h. In case of an error, the result array is uninitialized and must not be released.

Playback and capture devices available for the given mode can be listed, as well as the current operating systems default. The returned device values can be used to initialize the devices.
To query the default playback and capture device, call

To get a list of all available playback and capture devices for the specified mode, call

> **unsigned int ts3client_getPlaybackDeviceList(modeID, result); 
>   const char* modeID;
>
>   char**** result;
>
>   unsigned int ts3client_getCaptureDeviceList(modeID, result); 
>   const char* modeID;
>
>   char**** result;**

Parameters
• modeID
Defines the playback/capture mode to use. For different modes there might be different device lists. Valid modes are returned by
ts3client_getDefaultPlayBackMode / s3client_getDefaultCaptureMode and  ts3client_getPlaybackModeList / ts3client_getCaptureModeList.

• result
Address of a variable that receives a NULL-terminated array { { char* deviceName, char* deviceID }, { char* deviceName, char* deviceID }, ... , NULL }.
Unless the function returns an error, the elements of the array and the array itself need to be freed using ts3client_freeMemory.
Returns ERROR_ok on success, otherwise an error code as defined in public_errors.h. In case of an error, the result array is uninitialized and must not be released.

> **unsigned int ts3client_startConnection(serverConnectionHandlerID,identity,ip,port,nickname,defaultChannelArray,defaultChannelPassword,serverPassword);**
>
> uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID;   const char* identity;   const
>   char* ip; unsigned int port;   const char* nickname;   const char**
>   defaultChannelArray; // This the thingy I dont get const char*
>   defaultChannelPassword;   const char* serverPassword;

Parameters
• serverConnectionHandlerID
Unique identifier for this server connection. Created with ts3client_spawnNewServerConnectionHandler
• identity
The clients identity. This string has to be created by calling ts3client_createIdentity.
Please note an application should create the identity only once, store the string locally and reuse it for future connections.
• ip
Hostname or IP of the TeamSpeak 3 server.
If you pass a hostname instead of an IP, the Client Lib will try to resolve it to an IP, but the function may block for an unusually long period of time while resolving is taking place. If you are relying on the function to return quickly, we recommend to resolve the hostname yourself (e.g. asynchronously) and then call ts3client_startConnection with the IP instead of the hostname.
• port
UDP port of the TeamSpeak 3 server, by default 9987. TeamSpeak 3 uses UDP. Support for TCP might be added in the future.
• nickname
On login, the client attempts to take this nickname on the connected server. Note this is not necessarily the actually assigned nickname, as the server can modifiy the nickname ("gandalf_1" instead the requested "gandalf") or refuse blocked names.
• defaultChannelArray
String array defining the path to a channel on the TeamSpeak 3 server. If the channel exists and the user has sufficient rights and supplies the correct password if required, the channel will be joined on login.
To define the path to a subchannel of arbitrary level, create an array of channel names detailing the position of the default channel (e.g. "grandparent", "parent", "mydefault", "").  The array is terminated with a empty string.
Pass NULL to join the servers default channel.
• defaultChannelPassword
Password for the default channel. Pass an empty string if no password is required or no default channel is specified.
• serverPassword
Password for the server. Pass an empty string if the server does not require a password.
All strings need to be encoded in UTF-8 format

**Important**
Client Lib functions returning C-strings or arrays dynamically allocate memory which has to be freed by the caller using ts3client_freeMemory. It is important to only access and release the memory if the function returned ERROR_ok.
Should the function return an error, the result variable is uninitialized, so freeing or accessing it
could crash the application.
See the section Calling Client Lib functions for additional notes and examples.
A printable error string for a specific error code can be queried with
unsigned int ts3client_getErrorMessage(errorCode, error);
unsigned int errorCode;
char** error;
Parameters
• errorCode
The error code returned from all Client Lib functions.
• error
Address of a variable that receives the error message string, encoded in UTF-8 format. Unless the return value of the function is not ERROR_ok, the string should be released with ts3client_freeMemory.
**Example:**

```
unsigned int error;
anyID myID;
error = ts3client_getClientID(scHandlerID, &myID); /* Calling some Client Lib function */
if(error != ERROR_ok) {
    char* errorMsg;
    if(ts3client_getErrorMessage(error, &errorMsg) == ERROR_ok) 
    { /* Query printable error */
        printf("Error querying client ID: %s\n", errorMsg);
        ts3client_freeMemory(errorMsg); /* Release memory */
    }
}


type
  PPanyID = ^PAnyID;
  PanyID = ^anyID;
  anyID  = word;

var
   error: longword;
   errormsg: PAnsiChar;


procedure TfrmMain.RequestOnlineClients;
var
  ids : PanyID;
  pids : PanyID;
  aid : anyID;
begin
  error := ts3client_getClientList(FTSServerHandlerID, @ids);
  if (error <> ERROR_ok) then
  begin
    if (ts3client_getErrorMessage(error, @errormsg) = ERROR_ok) then
    begin
      LogMsg(Format('Error requesting online clients: %s', [errormsg]));
      ts3client_freeMemory(errormsg);
    end;
  end else
      begin
         pids := ids;
         while (pids^ <> 0) do
         begin
           aid := pids^;
           LogMsg(format('userid %u',[aid, getUserNickNameById(aid)]));
           inc(pids);
         end;
         ts3client_freeMemory(@pids^);  // here's potiential problem
      end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.RequestChannels;
var
  ids : PUint64;
  pids : PUint64;
  aid : uint64;
  channelname : PAnsiChar;

begin
  error := ts3client_getChannelList(FTSServerHandlerID, @ids);
  if (error <> ERROR_ok) then
  begin
    if (ts3client_getErrorMessage(error, @errormsg) = ERROR_ok) then
    begin
      LogMsg(Format('Error requesting channels: %s', [errormsg]));
      ts3client_freeMemory(errormsg);
    end;
  end else
    begin
       pids := ids;
       while (pids^ <> 0) do
       begin
         aid := pids^;
         LogMsg(format('channelid %u %s',[aid, getChannelNameById(aid)]));
         inc(pids);
       end;
       ts3client_freeMemory(@pids^);
    end;
end;

**// Added details 25-11-2014**
char* defaultMode;  

if(ts3client_getDefaultPlayBackMode(&defaultMode) == ERROR_ok) {
char*** array;  
    if(ts3client_getPlaybackDeviceList(defaultMode, &array) == ERROR_ok) {
       for(int i=0; array[i] != NULL; ++i) {
           printf("Playback device name: %s\n", array[i][0]); /* First element: Device name */  
           printf("Playback device ID: %s\n", array[i][1]); /* Second element: Device ID */  
           /* Free element */  
          ts3client_freeMemory(array[i][0]);  
          ts3client_freeMemory(array[i][1]);  
          ts3client_freeMemory(array[i]);  
       }  
   ts3client_freeMemory(array); /* Free complete array */  
   } else {  
     printf("Error getting playback device list\n");  
   }  
} else {  
printf("Error getting default playback mode\n");  
}  

Example to query all available playback devices:
char* defaultMode;  

if(ts3client_getDefaultPlayBackMode(&defaultMode) == ERROR_ok) {
char*** array;
if(ts3client_getPlaybackDeviceList(defaultMode, &array) == ERROR_ok) {
  for(int i=0; array[i] != NULL; ++i) {  
    printf("Playback device name: %s\n", array[i][0]); /* First element: Device name */  
    printf("Playback device ID: %s\n", array[i][1]); /* Second element: Device ID */  
    /* Free element */  
    ts3client_freeMemory(array[i][0]);  
    ts3client_freeMemory(array[i][1]);  
    ts3client_freeMemory(array[i]);  
}  
ts3client_freeMemory(array); /* Free complete array */  
} else {  
  printf("Error getting playback device list\n");  
}  
} else {  
printf("Error getting default playback mode\n");  
}  

procedure TfrmMain.ConnectServer2;
var
  version : PAnsiChar;
  DefaultChannelsArr : PPAnsiChar;
begin
  if Connected then Exit;

  if not ClientInitialized then
    InitializeClient;

  // Dbl Check if we can connect
  if ClientInitialized then
  try

    // Connect to server on localhost:9987 with nickname "client", no default channel, no default channel password and server password "secret"
    // error := ts3client_startConnection(FTSServerHandlerID, identity, '127.0.0.1', 9987, 'Delphi Client', nil, '', 'secret'); // example connection setup
    ts3check(ts3client_startConnection(FTSServerHandlerID, PAnsiChar(FSetup.ClientIdentity), PAnsiChar(FSetup.ServerAddress), FSetup.FServerPort, PAnsiChar(FSetup.NickName), nil, '', PAnsiChar(FSetup.ServerPassword)));
    { TODO -oMe -cImportant : Need to check how to convert ansistrings to UTF8 } // UnicodeToUtf8() // AnsiToUtf8()...


     // Query and print client lib version
    ts3check(ts3client_getClientLibVersion(@version));
    LogMsg(Format('Client lib version: %s', [version]));
    ts3client_freeMemory(version);  // Release dynamically allocated memory

     // Do not set connected here, wait for the callback connected state
  except
    on e: exception do
    begin
      UnInitializeClient; // clear the hole thing and start over
      LogMsg(Format('Error connecting: %s',[e.Message]));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: don't know about the TS3 SDK, but you might be freeing the wrong pointer (pids instead of ids), or you should free pids during that loop. Freeing it when it's past the array boundaries might be trouble.

Comment: We don't know anything about `ts3client_getClientList` or indeed `ts3client_getErrorMessage`. We also cannot see all the types and variables involved. Some are declared elsewhere. You've not provided any details here.

Comment: Added more details, hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd translate `ts3client_getClientList` like this:

```
function ts3client_getClientList(serverConnectionHandlerID: UInt64; 
  out result: PAnyID): Cardinal; cdecl; external '...';
```

I think that an `out` parameter is better than a double pointer. It makes the intent clearer.

Then to call the function I'd write it like this:

```
var
  ids: PAnyID;
  idarr: TArray<anyID>;
....
ts3check(ts3client_getClientList(serverConnectionHandlerID, ids));
try
  idarr := GetIDs(ids);
finally
  ts3check(ts3client_freeMemory(ids));
end;
```

Here, `ts3check` is a function that raises an exception if it is passed a return value other than `ERROR_ok`.

```
function ts3client_getErrorMessage(error: Cardinal; 
  out errormsg: PAnsiChar): Cardinal; cdecl; external '...';

....

procedure ts3check(error: Cardinal);
var
  errormsg: PAnsiChar;
  errorstr: string;
begin
  if error = ERROR_ok then
    exit;

  if ts3client_getErrorMessage(error, @errormsg) <> ERROR_ok then
    raise Ets3Error.CreateFmt('Error code %d', [error]);

  errorstr := UTF8ToUnicodeString(errormsg);
  ts3client_freeMemory(errormsg);
  raise Ets3Error.CreateFmt('Error code %d (%s)', [error, errorstr]);
end;
```

And you can implement `GetIDs` like this:

```
function GetIDs(const ids: PAnyID): TArray<anyID>;
var
  Count: Integer;
  p: PAnyID;
begin
  Count := 0;
  p := ids;
  while p^ <> 0 do 
  begin
    inc(Count);
    inc(p);
  end;

  SetLength(Result, Count);
  Count := 0;
  p := ids;
  while p^ <> 0 do 
  begin
    Result[Count] := p^;
    inc(Count);
    inc(p);
  end;
end;
```

Now, I don't imagine that you really want an array of IDs. You'd probably be happy to process the IDs inline. I don't want to get into how to do that though because that leads me into code of yours that I cannot see. You won't write the code exactly as I have done above, but you can hopefully use the above as a source of ideas.

The main point in all of this is to try to encapsulate as much of the messy boiler plate code as possible. Wrapping the call to `ts3client_getErrorMessage` makes the higher level code so much easier to read. Use things like `OleCheck` and `Win32Check` as inspiration.

One point I would make is that it feels wrong for this code to live inside a form. Normally it is cleaner to keep such code removed from your UI. Make a wrapper to this library that can be consumed by your UI code. Keep that wrapper in a dedicated unit and so hide away the gnarly details.

Comment: Thanks David, it makes a lot of sense what you show by example here, it also looks a lot more Delphi like that way - function GetIDs(const ids: PAnyID): TArray<anyID>; very nice indeed, I can make an overload for those ID's which is PUint64.
Wrapping it in a seperate unit also makes a lot of sense, great suggestion. I'll try it out and get back ;)

Comment: Hello again, I getting forward and your suggestions works well, I do however still have problems understanding the process of handling null terminated arrays of null terminated data, and when it gets to multi dim. arrays - I'm lost.

I have added two calls ts3client_getCaptureDeviceList (returns multi dim mixed array) and ts3client_startConnection which I need to parse an array of PAnsiChars to for the Default channel name(s). 

I know it's much to ask but could you help out? I have added code samples at the bottom of the code block.

Comment: That's a new question surely. It's not on to get me to debug your entire program in one question.